Unable to install any packages with apt in a brand new 24.04 installation because of libreoffice-help-zh-tw
I've never used Linux before and just installed Ubuntu 24.04.
Edit: I used the ZFS file system when I installed.
At the end of the installation, I got an error popup unable to securely remove '/usr/share/libreoffice/help/zh-TW/text/swriter/00/stylesmenu.html.dpkg-tmp': Invalid exchange but I could click OK and the system rebooted normally and I was able to log in fine.
I wanted to enable SSH so I tried to run this command: sudo apt install openssh-server
However, for some reason, there's some package that needs to be removed too:
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ncurses-term openssh-sftp-server ssh-import-id
Suggested packages:
  molly-guard monkeysphere ssh-askpass
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libreoffice-help-zh-tw
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ncurses-term openssh-server openssh-sftp-server ssh-import-id

However this always fails:
Fetched 752 kB in 0s (1,505 kB/s)        
Requesting to save current system state
Successfully saved as "autozsys_18acft"
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 231711 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libreoffice-help-zh-tw (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4) ...
dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-help-zh-tw (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/share/libreoffice/help/zh-TW/text/swriter/00/stylesmenu.html.dpkg-tmp':
 Invalid exchange
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreoffice-help-zh-tw
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.

This error occurs no matter what package I try to install since it always tries to remove the libreoffice package too.
I tried to uninstall libreoffice with:
sudo apt-get remove --purge "libreoffice*"
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove

But this gives the same error as above.
I was able to update firefox from Ubuntu Software (from the sidebar) as well as install VSCode, so it seems to just be related to apt.
Any ideas?
Edit: I tried to manually remove the file referenced as was suggested by a comment, but alas the 'Invalid Exchange' error prevents that as well:
cjones@control:~/Desktop$ sudo mv /usr/share/libreoffice/help/zh-TW/text/swriter/00/stylesmenu.html.dpkg-tmp ~/
mv: cannot stat '/usr/share/libreoffice/help/zh-TW/text/swriter/00/stylesmenu.html.dpkg-tmp': Invalid exchange
cjones@control:~/Desktop$ sudo rm /usr/share/libreoffice/help/zh-TW/text/swriter/00/stylesmenu.html.dpkg-tmp
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/libreoffice/help/zh-TW/text/swriter/00/stylesmenu.html.dpkg-tmp': Invalid exchange


Have you tried to remove the file manually ? Maybe it is a leftover from the install.
Try:
sudo rm /usr/share/libreoffice/help/zh-TW/text/swriter/00/stylesmenu.html.dpkg-tmp
Then retry to install openssh server.

I also get 'Invalid Exchange' when doing rm (or mv) on the file.  Is this a Ubuntu thing?  I can't seem to find anything on the internet with this particular wording.  Is it maybe a hardware thing?  Or maybe because I used ZFS when I installed?

could be filesystem problem so make a check first. sudo apt-get clean and sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/* and sudo apt update & sudo apt install --reinstall libreoffice-help-zh-tw

Based on the result from https://www.google.com/search?q=zfs+Invalid+exchange it seems to be an internal error in zfs; POSSIBLY triggered by hardware problems; drive, cabling or interface hardware. The fault MAY be related exactly to that file only, e.g. a failing block on the disk. Try a rename, mv ... to a name other than the current might work as at least a temporary "remedy" .

tried @nobody steps, but still got invalid exchange:
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-help-zh-tw_1%
3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to stat './usr/share/libreoffice/help/zh-TW/text/shared/explorer/databas
e/migrate_macros.html' (which was about to be installed): Invalid exchange
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-help-zh-tw_1%3a7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4_all.d
eb


Since this is a new computer, i'll just wipe it and retry with LVM instead for now based on @Hannu reply.

Based on the result from google.com/search?q=zfs+Invalid+exchange
it seems to be an internal error in zfs;
POSSIBLY triggered by hardware problems; drive, cabling or interface hardware.
The fault MAY be related exactly to that file only, e.g. a failing block on the disk.
A rename might be a short-term remedy,
mv ... to a name other than the current
- then run apt and see what it recons about the situation.

Unfortunately, it seems like I cannot touch this file at all. I will try reinstalling with lvm next.  I might try switching the sata port too, maybe it's a problem with the controller? Or a new sata wire.

Check if you can see the actual disk blocks occupied by the file; it might allow to test the disk - on those blocks - to see if they actually work. Formatting (not quick) might also work, but will probably take a good amount of time.

I highly suspect some hardware issue on the motherboard as it is over 10 years old.   The SSD is only ~4 years old and only moderately used.  But now the OS is failing to boot with some errors: Failed to mount /var/lib, Failed to start Flush Journal to Persistent Storage and something like 30 dependency failures.  I swapped to another SATA port and wire and is still fails to boot with BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.SPT4._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/psargs-330) (and a couple of similar lines).
This is a wider problem I'll need to investigate.
